# Default Table Height Issue

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table which contains 2 `<td>` and both the `<td>` contains 2 separate images but its giving me weird height issue.

Its working perfectly in compatibility view but giving issues in non-compatibility view, the same issue is there in chrome browser.

Here is my jsfiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/7qbM8/

My Code :

```
<table id="tbleHeader" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td><a style="width: auto;" href="#"><img style="height: 43px;" src="~/images/iqi.jpg" runat="server" id="imgLogo" alt="" /></a></td>
            <td onmouseover="ShowParentMenu()"><h1 id="logout" ><a href="#"  title="Logout"></a></h1></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Here is the image of my problem 
The blue is the height which i have not assigned but by default its taking so i do not want that height in my table.

[image: .]

Comment: not understand what u expect?

Comment: Let me rephrase my question.

Comment: you want to set full td height?

Comment: you must reset h1 margin as 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the id logout has a margin, this will fix it for me:

```
#logout {
 margin: 0px; 
}
```

if i understand you right this solve the problem

The margin is becouse it is a h1 that has a margin by default

jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/7qbM8/4/

Answer (score 1):

### Check [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7qbM8/7/)

Add this property in this `h1#logout`

```
 margin:0;
```